# Core Data app crashing when using setValue:forKey: for many-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have gone over this over and over, and cannot for the life of me figure out why assigning a relationship through setValue:forKey: is not working.  My method is below.

```
-(void)saveNewCartItemName:(NSString *)name Price:(float)price Qty:(int)qty Tax:(int)tax inCart:(NSDate *)cartDate{
    NSManagedObject *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *query = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Cart"];
    NSLog(@"cartDate = %@", cartDate);
    [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cartDate = %@", cartDate]];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *queryResults = [[self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:query error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"queryResults count = %d", [queryResults count]);
    if ([queryResults count] == 1) [newItem setValue:[queryResults objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"cartThatHasItem"];
    [newItem setValue:name forKey:@"itemName"];
    [newItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:price] forKey:@"itemPrice"];
    [newItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:qty] forKey:@"itemQty"];
    [newItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tax] forKey:@"itemTax"];

    [self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

The line that it crashes on every time is:

```
if ([queryResults count] == 1) [newItem setValue:[queryResults objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"cartThatHasItem"];
```

My NSLog shows that there is a NSManagedObject to assign the relationship to, and I have double checked the name in the forKey: that there are no typos. All that Xcode tells me is that it prints out '(null)' on my console and then tells me 'libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception' on the next line.

Why is it crashing? And how do I fix it?

Update: That's the entire error message.

```
2012-07-03 18:28:57.844 appName[3063:11603] (null)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: can you post the exact error in full here?

Comment: do you have exception breakpoint turned on?

Comment: _[newItem setValue:name forKey:@"itemName"_, what's wrong here? No `];`??

Comment: @Stretch I at one point had the break point there, and once everything worked up to that point, I commented out that line and let it run, everything else works just fine.

Comment: @Kjuly Sorry, don't know how that got left off, it is in my code, will update in question.

Comment: What is your queryResults.count? And can you NSLog your [queryResults objectAtIndex:0]; ?

Comment: @Jamie My [queryResults count] is 1, and I NSLog'd both the attributes for that NSManagedObject and they are exactly what I expect them to be.

Comment: @tarheel That may be so, but I would make sure that you can log from the array and it is not null. Because you're crashing and it's not obvious, it's probably best to separate your code out so you can identify the exact call that's crashing

Comment: @Jamie Is there a way to NSLog a NSManagedObject directly? Otherwise, I did this `NSLog(@"queryResults date = %@", ((Cart *)[queryResults objectAtIndex:0]).cartDate);`, and got the result I expected. And I separated the if statement from the setValue:forKey: call and it is still the setValue:forKey: that is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no enough debug info... Cause you only need to check whether `queryResults` has an object, so I will use

```
[newItem setValue:[queryResults lastObject] forKey:@"cartThatHasItem"];
```

instead of

```
if ([queryResults count] == 1) [newItem setValue:[queryResults objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"cartThatHasItem"];
```

Not sure whether it'll solve your issue, but worth trying. :)

---

#### EDIT

Through your question title *'... for many-to-many relationship'*, I wonder what's the relationship between `cartThatHasItem` & `Cart`? If it is many to one or many to many, then the `cartThatHasItem`'s data type will be `NSSet`. So, you need to wrap the `[queryResults objectAtIndex:0]`' like

```
[newItem setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:[queryResults objectAtIndex:0]]
           forKey:@"cartThatHasItem"];
```

, or you can use

```
[newItem addCartThatHasItem:[queryResults objectAtIndex:0]]
```

instead. (`addCartThatHasItem:` will be added automatically when you generate your Cart model.)

---

#### EDIT 2

The Cart model should be like this:

```
@interface Cart : NSManagedObject

//...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *cartThatHasItem;

@end

@interface Cart (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

//...
- (void)addCartThatHasItemObject:(CartThatHasItem *)value;
- (void)removeCartThatHasItemObject:(CartThatHasItem *)value;
- (void)addCartThatHasItem:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCartThatHasItem:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

if you generate your model correctly.

Comment: @tarheel what's the relationship between `cartThatHasItem` & `Cart`?

Comment: cartThatHasItem is Item's relationship to Cart.

Comment: I definitely see the addCartThatHasItem in my Core Data generated NSManagedObject subclasses, but when I write what you have it gives me the error that there is "No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObject' declares the selector 'addCartThatHasItem:". Which I imagine is due the the 'newItem' being declared as a NSManagedObject, not a Item just yet. Do you know how to clear that issue up?

Comment: @tarheel have you generated model correctly? See the new version.

Comment: my file is exactly the same as yours. Went back and tried your 2 options from the first Edit again, and the `[newItem setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:[queryResults objectAtIndex:0]]
           forKey:@"cartThatHasItem"];` worked. Must have been a typo on my part the first time around. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that your not checking the error object. If an error occurs then queryResults will likely be = nil and you subsequent attempt to check count is going to crash you. At the very least check for the nil condition:

```
NSMutableArray *queryResults = [[self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:query error:&error] mutableCopy];

if( queryResults == nil ) return; // Or better yet check the value of Error.
```